# Android Share Text on Facebook instead of Link

Tags: android, facebook, share

I am working on **Text Sharing** on From my **Android Application** .  I have used the following code.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");                         
String text="http://google.com";
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,text);
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Message");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
```

If I will this code means it shares link correctly and shows like following image !
[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGbSJ.png)

When I am using normal text like "sample content" means it is not accepting and showing the text .... I need to share the text instead of that link .. please help me ...

Its working correctly for **Gmail** and **Twitter** also.

Waiting for better response..... Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation with the (stupid) Facebook app. They know about it, but apparently don't want to fix it.

Your only option is to implement Facebook sharing using their API.

Comment: @Ollie.. By using  Facebook  API  is it possible to get the user verification every time before posting the content... right now i have a sample like "first time we need the registration .. if we done once .. by clicking share button it will post the content automatically in the Facebook wall ... neither i need User confirmation .... thanks in advance .....

Comment: I suggest asking a new question, and tagging it appropriately. Do remem ber to vote up answers and accept responses, as more people will reply to your questions in future.